# div align doesn't work with css

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <style>
        .main{
            align:center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        Arbitary text
    </div>
</body>
```

-in that case text is on the left, but when i change to:

```
<div align="center">
    Arbitary text
</div>
```

- everything ok.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

syntax error. It should `text-align:center` not `align:center`. or use `margin:0px auto`

```
.main{
text-align:center;
}
```

or

```
.main{
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.main{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you  "text-align" Instead of "align" property in css
    .main{
    text-align:center;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are missing doctype before the html element starts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

To place div and text at centre, use:

```
.main{
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `text-align` in CSS (not `align`). From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align):

> The `text-align` CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. `text-align` does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.

You can write another values like `left` or `right`.

```
.main {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8ssu41x/).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the original HTML 4.01 specfication, the `align` attribute controls how text is aligned within a block level element (left, center, right, justify).

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2

However, the `align` attribute is deprecated (obsolete) but since browsers support it for
backwards compatibility, the attribute still works.

As of CSS 2.1, the `align` attribute was superseded by the `text-align` property.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop

Using the CSS rule for text alignment is the preferred method.

As stated in earlier postings, `align` is not a CSS property, so that is why your CSS rule
does not work.